# Where can I get Ubuntu 11.04 Beta

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

I was wondering where can I get an early release of Ubuntu 11.04 either RC or Beta/Alpha.

I am interested in developing for it and I was wondering where I can get it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching Google for "ubuntu beta download" finds this link: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily/current/

Answer (score 1):

You can get 11.04 beta 1 from http://releases.ubuntu.com/natty/

This gives you options for desktop and server editions.  You also get the beta release instead of the daily build.